# jQueryMobile - filtering in listview and pressing Go on keypad doesn't hide keyboard

Tags: ipad, jquery-mobile

In jQuery Mobile there are filtered listviews. After entering text into filter, list gets filtered but pressing GO button doesn't hide the keyboard.

User expects that keyboard will hide after pressing GO. 
Is there any way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the focus manually from the input field with Javascript like this:

```
$('.ui-listview-filter .ui-input-text').live('keyup', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        // 'Go' pressed
        $('.ui-listview-filter .ui-input-text').trigger('blur');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try changing the focus after the key is pressed. For example:

```
//this will un-select the text box, hiding keyboard
$('#searchInputId').blur();

//this will focus on something else, hiding keyboard
$('#somethingOtherThanTheSearch').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Variant of Pablo's answer which works on my outdated version of jQuery (mobile):

```
  // this is here to close the on-screen keyboards of mobile devices when the "go" button is used
  $("input[data-type='search']").on('keyup', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) { // Enter or 'Go' pressed
      event.target.blur(); // remove focus on the search field so keyboard goes away
    }
 });
```